# Maven compiler plugin does not see Lombok's annotations

Tags: java, spring, maven, lombok, maven-compiler-plugin

in my application I have 3 modules like this:

```
permissions (parent pom)
|---permission-api (just api, without main spring class)
|---permission-service (spring boot app)
```

In parent pom in main module I have pom which contains:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.3</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<modules>
    <module>permissions-api</module>
    <module>permissions-service</module>
</modules>
```

and some dependencies. Now I want to build my whole project with maven clean install. Permission-api module is build (there is no problem with lombok annotations). In pom only reference to lombok is:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

Anyway when I try to build only permission-serivce or entire project, I've got compilation errors like this:

```
cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   method getPermissionsList()
[ERROR]   location: variable employee of type permissions.model.entity.Employee
```

I know that I should add maven-compiler-plugin to pom.xml (I tried to add this to parent pom too) and I did but it does not help:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Can you tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's hard to help you when you don't disclose the complete poms and the relevant classes (Employee, and whatever class has that variable in it).

Answer (score 2):

Meanwhile I found a solution. Everything started to works when I add:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Probably that missing dependency was causing first compilation error and maven compiler incorectly showed next lombok "missing annotations" as compilation errors too.

Answer (score 1):

Dependency, as in [projectlombok.org](https://projectlombok.org/setup/maven), should be in scope 'provided', meaning that it's required only for compilation, but not needed in runtime:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.22</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

This should be enough.

Comment: Still does not work :( I dont know why in permissions-api it works every time and in permission-service it doesn't work no matter if I contain maven-compiler-plugin in pom or not.

Comment: Same or similar problem here. Configured lombok dependency in parent pom and this ought to be enough, shouldn't it? Or do we still need to specify annotationProcessorPath? lombok however does not generate getters, setters, logs in child modules. BTW everything looks good in eclipse ...

java 17, maven compiler plugin 3.10.1, lombok version 1.18.24

Comment: @r-uu you need to explicit enable lombok. It would be enough to have it as a dependency. As in: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71450923/1676068

I'm assuming that you already have a dependency management defined in parent pom as in my answer above. Then each child needs a (simple) dependency. No version and scope is then required.

Answer (score 0):

When you use optional true, you are preventing dependency being transferred to its children transitively. Remove optional and you should be fine.

```html
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
</dependency>
```